# Django froms submit action and HttpResponseRedirect difference

Tags: python, django, forms

Referring from the [form topic](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/#the-view) of django documentation, if in a view function I write,

```
if form.is_valid():
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
```

And in the form template I give the action like,

```
<form action="/your-name/" method="post">
```

Then on submit the form will go to the view mapped tho `/your-name/` url in `urls.py` but what about the `HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')` line in the function from where I rendering the form? If a form is valid then I save the form. but what will be the `url` in the `action` of the form. now `def get_name(request):` is the function mapped to `/user/` url. I hope you understand my confusion here. need some help.

Comment: randomly down voting is not a good practice. you need to specify the reason otherwise you are only decreasing my reputation and not helping me or the SO site.

Answer (score 2):

This is an exemple of the "post redirect get" pattern - if a post is succesfull (the form was valid and the processing went ok), it's good practice to return a redirect, which will be followed by a get from the user-agent on the url you redirected to. It avoids multiple submissions if the user try to reload the page.

Where you redirect to is up to you - you can just redirect to the same view (usually displaying a success message to the user), or redirect to another view.

As a side note: hardcoding urls is a bad practice in Django, you should use the url reverse feature instead.

Comment: I am totally new to django. So I did not totally understand all the terms you have explained here but I appreciate. would you give examples (code snippet) with your answer?

Comment: Except for the url reverse stuff (which is fully documented here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls), it's nothing specific to Django, just ordinary web stuff. If you're new to web programming, the best thing you can do is to first learn how the HTTP protocol works.

Comment: My confusion is between the `action` field in html form and corresponding url mapping function in the view. Your answer does not provide to the point answer so i asked for example. using `url reverse` is not what i am concerned right now.

Comment: The `action` param in a form is the url to which the form will be sent (either for a post or get request). Which view you map it to in your urlconf is up to you. In the example you posted, the redirect will redirect the user-agent to the url `/thanks/` - there again which view you map it to is up to you. If my answer "does not provide to the point answer" then please clarify your question.